# Filtering through a list of tables to only include useful lines

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

Given the lack of elegance with the data

the record sheet continues for many MANY rows, each entry having its own set of identical headings

[image]

I was hoping to just extract the data from rows 7, 14 and so on, then populate the data into a simple table to be used on the 'Protocol Summary' form, then sort them all into alphanumeric order based on the data that is in the A column so they all become grouped by 'Event Type'.

Because the potential data that could be under the 'Event Type' heading can vary a lot (generally has the format of [number 1-32/letter/number 1-30] but can also be all letters, with a few thousand possibilities, I thought it might be easier to filter the other lines OUT, given they don't change.  I would love to redesign the table, but unfortunately it's not my table so I have to work with what I'm given.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Geoff, if you can do this stuff they ought to pay you more. As for me, I can't even figure out your question, let alone what my answer might be.

Comment: Seems like you just need to loop down ColA looking for "Event Type" then take the next row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop over your sheet up to the last used row, starting from Row 7 and stepping 7 rows each iteration.

Within each iteration, each cell in the row is written into an array which is then written to another sheet ready for sorting (however you want to do that).

This code is sample and may not work by copy/paste.

- I have written this in the `Sheet1` code module, so `Me` refers to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")`.
- I have made this from a blank workbook and did not rename any sheets therefore you will need to make adjustments to any sheet references to match your appropriate sheet names.
- The code will only reference columns A, B and C in the `TargetRow` (I only tested with 3 columns of data as I don't know your working range). I'll reference what to update to extend this after the code block.
- Currently the array is put back into `Sheet2` starting from cell `A2`. This is assuming row 1 contains table headers as this will write the data directly into the table format. Naturally if you want to change where the data is written, change the cell it is written to (when writing an array to sheet, you only need to define the top left cell of the range it is written to, Excel works out the rest based on the size and dimensions of the array).

---

```
Sub WriteEverySeventhRowToAnotherSheet()

Dim SeventhRowCount As Long
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim TargetCell As Variant
Dim TargetRow As Range
Dim ArrFirstDimension As Long
Dim ArrSecondDimension As Long

lastrow = Me.Range("A" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim myArray(1 To lastrow / 7, 1 To 3)
ArrFirstDimension = 1
ArrSecondDimension = 1

'------------------Loop over every 7th row and enter row data to array---------------
For SeventhRowCount = 7 To lastrow Step 7
    Set TargetRow = Me.Range("A" & SeventhRowCount & ":C" & SeventhRowCount)
    For Each TargetCell In TargetRow
        If Not ArrSecondDimension > UBound(myArray) Then
            myArray(ArrFirstDimension, ArrSecondDimension) = TargetCell
            'Debug.Print TargetCell
            ArrSecondDimension = ArrSecondDimension + 1
        End If
    Next TargetCell
    ArrFirstDimension = ArrFirstDimension + 1
    ArrSecondDimension = 1
    Set TargetRow = Nothing
Next SeventhRowCount

'---------------------Write array to another sheet------------------
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
Destination.Resize(UBound(myArray, 1), UBound(myArray, 2)).Value = myArray

End Sub
```

To extend the number of columns the loop will write to the array, change the following instance of `C` to the correct column letter (in the below line the range is set from Column A to Column C):

- `Set TargetRow = Me.Range("A" & SeventhRowCount & ":C" & SeventhRowCount)`

Also change the 2nd dimension of the Array to match the number of the Column set above (i.e Column E = 5 and Column L = 13 etc.) - You need to replace the number `3` with the correct number.

- `ReDim myArray(1 To lastrow / 7, 1 To 3)`